# Unable to get firebase-ui-auth from mavenCentral when I build an app with ./gradlew lintDebug

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, jcenter, maven-central

I'm trying to change a source of an android app's libraries from `JCenter` to `MavenCentral`, because the `JCenter` will be closed.

I've checked that `firebase-ui-auth v7.1.1` and `v7.2.0` are in `MavenCentral`, but when I build the app with `./gradlew lintDebug`, the `firebase-ui-auth` is not found and the build is failed.

I've also checked that, if I use assembleDebug to build, or I run the app on AndroidStudio, the build succeeds and the app runs on a mobile devise.

I've also tried creating a new project on the AndroidStudio, and done following steps, but the build was still failed.

- Add `implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0"` // or `7.1.1`
- Remove `jcenter()`

I put some logs below. Any idea why, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

**./gradlew lintDebug:**

```
 * What went wrong:
 Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintDebug'.
 > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
    > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:.
      Required by:
          project :app > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0
```

**build.gradle:**

```
 buildscript {
 ...
   repositories {
     google()
     mavenCentral()
     ...
   }
   ...
 }
 
 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
         ...
     }
 }
 
 ...
```

**build.gradle(:app):**

```
 ...
 
 dependencies {
 ...
   implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0" // or 7.1.1
 ...
 }
```

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.firebaseui/firebase-ui-auth/7.2.0/aar

Comment: Found any solution>